# What is the approach to deal with a blatant copy of the answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Today I have found a [question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049428/1090562) to it is a blatant copy of the answer, which was given like a year ago. Person just copied significant copy of the code, throw away test suites and presented as his. Only the comment below the answer (by some other guy) reveals the origin of the answer.

I downvoted the copy, but the question arise - how to deal with this. From one point of view, the answer is correct, all the content on SO is free to use, so the person is not violating the rules. But this is so weak and can be so destructive if everyone would be just copying others stuff and pretend it is their solution.

Therefore I think, that even downvote is not enough (person already got 2 upvotes), to for him to get punishment, he need to have like 10 downvotes (even then he will just break even). How should people behave in such situation?

Comment: Flag and let a moderator deal with it?

Answer (score 4):

> From one point of view, the answer is correct, all the content on SO is free to use, so the person is not violating the rules. But this is so weak and can be so destructive if everyone would be just copying others stuff and pretend it is their solution.

Free to use **with attribution**. If the attribution is missing, then it is in violation of [our CC-BY-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0). Answers within the same site are not an exception to this requirement.

Your name and profile are attached to every post that you contribute to the site. Therefore it is assumed that any content you post was written by you, **unless otherwise stated**. Copying the work of others and passing it off as your own is called plagiarism, and is indeed harmful to the community — and especially to the original author.

Plagiarized posts should be flagged for moderator attention with a link to the original source, although note that this answer in particular does *try* to cite an external source but has unfortunately misattributed. Whether this is an honest mistake or deliberate, it needs to be corrected by the user who posted the answer. I'll leave a comment and give them a bit of time and if they don't respond, the answer will be removed.